# Android how can I get screenshot bitmap?

Tags: java, android, screenshot, root

To make screenshots I use this code:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();

os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

But this is veeery slow! Maybe because phone is saving this image on storage.
To get this bitmap I use this code:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+         
File.separator +"img.png");
```

But that's pretty slow! Is possible to get bitmap but not save it? Maybe it will be much faster?

Comment: at same time 'volume-down' && 'power button' 

that dumps the screen storage and you should then get a 'save' dialog

Comment: Ohh... I want to make it programmically.

Comment: since its not your app. you may have to pre-empt hardware buffer in fashion similar to ALSA capture for audio.

Comment: @kubaork did you fin some solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

here you go [View.getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) returns  the currently drawn View suface.

```
view.setsetDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
final Bitmap screenshot = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);    

//use bitmap
```

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mention it. I want to make screenshot of another application, so I cant use your method

Comment: And didn't you forget to mention that you have a rooted phone?

Comment: @greenapps to use the drawing cache? no, thats an public api

Comment: Sorry that was addressed to @kubaork as he said "I forgot to mention". What he wants starts with a rooted phone.